# How can I validate a cell phone number actually belongs to the device?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, phone-number

I am trying to put together a registration process in which one of the pieces of information is the cell phone number.  I know through iOS SDK I can get the phone number, but Apple will reject the application.

If I have the user enter the phone number, how can I be sure that user isn't entering some "fake/spoofed" phone number.  I want to make sure the number entered belongs to that specific device and be able to pass that phone number to a REST service handling the registration of that device.

I realize open access to the phone number is a privacy issue, but there has to be some way to get the cell number with the users approval AND validate that number came from that device.

I will be targeting iOS 6.x +  Not sure which versions of Android yet.

As always, any thoughts or ideas are welcome.

Comment: Have the device send a text to the number the user enters, then check for the incoming message from that same number.

Answer (score 3):

You can send a validation code to the mobile via SMS, so you can prevent spam and fraud. For this you need a SMS gateway provider.

Check Text Anywhere, they provide an API for Java, .Net, and etc. (i couldnt link the url...)

Or [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com).

Comment: Good info on the API for sending the SMS text message.  I was more curious about how to make sure the phone number the user enters (in the app) is actually the phone number for the device.  Not just anyone can receive the validation code.